# I want to put a input variable before print (menu) but I want it to be printed after the menu

Tags: python, variables, input, boolean, variable-assignment

Can anyone help I am a beginner? I want the variable choice to be displayed after the menu is but I need the variable to be on top so the name inserted can be shown beside add player name.

```py
choice = input("Input your menu choice: ")
choice = False

if choice == "1":
    name = input("What is your name? ")

print("                  Menu                    ")
print("------------------------------------------")
print(f"[1] Add player name: {name} ")
print("[2] Play guess the capital city")
print("[3] End game")
print("------------------------------------------")

choice True
```

I tried to use a Boolean but it didn't so any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's a bit confusing how your code is laid out. What is `choice = False` meant to do here? All that does is overwrite the menu choice with the literal `False`. Leave out that boolean assignment, and just `print(choice)` at the end, perhaps?

Comment: You need to find out about loops.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a string first like this?

```
import random

name = 'Anonomous'

playing = True

while playing == True:
    print("                  Menu                    ")
    print("------------------------------------------")
    print(f"[1] Add player name: {name} ")
    print("[2] Play guess the capital city")
    print("[3] End game")
    print("------------------------------------------")

    choice = input("Input your menu choice: ")

    if choice == "1":
        name = input("What is your name? ")

    if choice == "2":
        winner = False
        capital_city = random.choice(['London', 'Paris', 'Rome'])
        while not winner:
            guess = input("What capital city am I thinking of? ").title()
            if guess == capital_city:
                print(f'You won!!! I was thinking of {guess}..')
                winner = True
            else:
                print(f'No, it was not {guess}, guess again..')
    
    if choice == "3":
        playing = False
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```py
choice = input("Input your menu choice: ")
choice = False
```

will make *choice* always equal *False*, also you should avoid changing types of variables like above: from str to bool. Assuming that you want working and well-structured console game:

```py
name = 'Unnamed'  # Set default value of name.

# Create game loop using infinite while.
while True:
    # Display the menu: use string multiplication and a little of math.
    print(' ' * 18 + 'Menu' + ' ' * 18)
    print('-' * 40)
    print(f"[1] Add player name: {name} ")
    print("[2] Play guess the capital city")
    print("[3] End game")
    print('-' * 40)

    # Get choice from user.
    choice = input("\nInput your menu choice: ")

    # Perform proper action for a choice selected. 
    if choice == '1':
        name = input("What is your name? ")
    elif choice == '2':
        # Load your game ...
        ...
    # If player wants to end game, it is equivalent to exiting
    # loop using 'break' statement.
    elif choice == '3':
        break
    else:
        # Define what happens if player inputted unsupported choice.
        ...

    # It is a common way to clear screen in python console
    # applications/games, if fourty lines of empty lines is not
    # sufficient increase amount of them.
    print('\n' * 40)

# Here you can save for instance player score or nickname and
# later read it at the beginning of file (before the game loop).
```